# Boost::asio::ssl OpenSSL not compiling

Tags: openssl, boost-asio

I'm using boost::asio::ssl. I have installed openssl via sudo apt-get install openssl.
In my makefile I link openssl via -lssl.

When compiling I am getting the error:
fatal error: openssl/conf.h: No such file or directory

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or if I'm including the library incorrectly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may not have the necessary development files. Try installing the libssl-dev package with

```
  sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

this may solve your problem

Comment: So that means that internally ASIO has dependency on Open SSL ?