# Building Openssl source for compiling boost

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, fedora

note. I have seen and read  [Boost::asio::ssl OpenSSL not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021525/boostasiossl-openssl-not-compiling)

[source file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp)

I am having some issues build the boost example ssl server on linux fedora 64 I think its version 15 or 16. It is a university machine so we do not have root access and since is the weekend I am accessing a machine via SSH.
We do not have root and openssl is not installed.
I built the boost library no program and the example server builds fine. I then tried to build the latest `openssl` library from source. I extracted to `~/Dev/opensslSource`

```
Cd ~/Dev/opensslSource
 ./config --prefix=~/Dev/openssl --openssldir=~/Dev/openssl
Make
Make install
```

Now either the problem exists there or in how I am including and linking.
So then in my boostexamples folder I did saved the example [sslserver.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp)
And used the following to build.

```
g++ -I ~/Dev/boost_1_52_0/ -I ~/Dev/openssl/include -L ~/Dev/boost_1_52_0/stage/lib -L ~/Dev/openssl server.cpp -o server -lboost_system -lssl –lpthread
```

The errors are almost endless. I cant even see them all. But they are all just undefided references I believe.

```
d1_enc.c:(.text+0x10c): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_size'
d1_enc.c:(.text+0x12f): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cipher'
d1_enc.c:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_block_size'
d1_enc.c:(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference to `EVP_Cipher'
d1_enc.c:(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `EVP_Cipher'
d1_enc.c:(.text+0x34b): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_block_size'
d1_enc.c:(.text+0x363): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_block_size'
d1_enc.c:(.text+0x375): undefined reference to `RAND_bytes'
```

So after the first few comments I have changed the build to.

```
g++ -I ~/Dev/boost_1_52_0/ -I ~/Dev/openssl/include -L ~/Dev/boost_1_52_0/stage/lib –L ~/Dev/openssl/lib server.cpp -o server -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread
```

Error now.

```
/home/andrew/Dev/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `dlopen'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/home/andrew/Dev/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x381): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x460): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/andrew/Dev/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_var':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x4e1): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x5c0): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/andrew/Dev/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x637): undefined reference to `dlopen'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x6ae): undefined reference to `dlclose'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x6e5): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/andrew/Dev/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x781): undefined reference to `dladdr'
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x7e9): undefined reference to `dlerror'
/home/andrew/Dev/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_unload':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x84a): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Maybe try `-lcrypto` as well? `-lssl` only links in the SSL part of OpenSSL, but that part depends on the crypto library. Put it after `-lssl` on the command line.

Comment: Also, try to put `-lboost_system` *after* `-lssl` .

Comment: Ok I am just logging in now my ssh expired.. wont be a minute. thanks guys.

Comment: @us2012 wouldn't Boost depend on OpenSSL and not the other way around?

Comment: @OmriBarel You're right, of course.

Comment: on topic - there is a different error now I will edit that in to the main question

Comment: Try to add `-ldl` after `-lcrypto`...

Comment: `dlopen` etc are symbols from libdl, add `-ldl`.

Comment: Built! Thank you Omri Barel and us2012. Would one of you like to submit and answer. Shame I can only best one. Heads or tails?

Comment: I'll leave it to us2012 to ruin his perfect reputation of 2222 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a few libraries from your linking options: libssl depends on libcrypto, which in turn depends on libdl. All in all, you will need

`-lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lpthread`.